# Customer Fields for Edit on Admin Side Are Not Showing Up

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, customer, adminform

My Magento version is 1.8.1.0. The fields are missing on the customer edit page on admin side. Nothing shows up after I clicked on the green rows. How do I resolve this problem? Please see screenshot in the comment below.

Comment: Screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/hjZDN